# Can a tilted angle map view be implemented using OpenLayers and how?

Tags: gis, openlayers, openlayers-3

By 'Tilted angle' I mean perspective, like a GPS Navigator app usually has.
If OpenLayers is capable then does it require a special/varied map service?

Comment: http://openlayers.org/ol3-cesium/examples/main.html

Comment: I meant like
http://apk-dl.com/detail/screenshot/NS6MB0gs1DMftnd21h0ezPxMF4piGbp_j0lnzEU8AZt6delZOy4OJgf3xqOqnYpC2lI=h500.png

Comment: After you click "enable" you can control the angle by shift/ctrl/alt+mouse drag. OL is not capable of doing this out of the box as of now.

Comment: Perfect Thanks!! Will the demo remain in place or did you make it purposefully? Because Iv linked my project docs to it and we need it for a few months.

Comment: I'm not the author, I just copied over the suggestion from an identical question asked a few days ago (and already deleted, you can still find it in Google's cache as of today) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37571904/how-to-obtain-this-perspective-view-in-openlayers

Answer (score 0):

Question answered very nicely above in the comments by kryger.